# Which waypoints are returned by API and in what order?

Tags: uber-api

Which waypoints are returned by API? I need to know if it will include only waypoints between moment where passenger is picked up and dropped off, or will it also include waypoints before passenger is picked up?

Also, are the waypoints returned in correct order? Is there plans to add estimated ETA's to each waypoint?

Comment: Hi Tristan-- we are looking into your series of questions. Trying to get a hold of the engineer who implemented waypoints in the API. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The waypoints include any upcoming pickup or dropoff stops scheduled before your user’s final destination. We don't include waypoints about the other POOL rider after your user's destination, since from your user's perspective, the trip is over.

As the [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get) states, the waypoint indicates whether it is a pickup or dropoff type and which rider it is associated with. The waypoints themselves are ordered and update as the trip progresses.

So, consider a situation where your user gets picked up at `Home` and dropped off at `Gym`, and is matched with another rider will be picked up in the middle of your user's trip at `Downtown` then dropped off `Somewhere` after your user finishes their trip.

The waypoints before your user gets picked up would show:

`[Home, Downtown, Gym]`

Once your user is picked up, the waypoints would update to show:

`[Downtown, Gym]`

Since the `Home` waypoint has passed. Note we never return `Somewhere` since that is after your user's dropoff.

Answer (score 0):

You see just the waypoints that affect your ETA, i.e. on the way to your pickup and on the way to your dropoff.

Specifically: "We show waypoints after your pickup but before your dropoff. Nothing beyond that (for privacy reasons)."

No further plans or changes here at the moment. Let us know if you have any different experience when you test.

Comment: So there is no way to differentiate a waypoint before and after dropoff? Or is there something I'm missing?